# Getting null value insert during bulk updates using open xml

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My database fields are

```
Id which is primary key and auto increment
imagename varchar(max)
imagepath varchar(max)
isdeleted bit
```

Now i am doing bulk insert using openxml.  It inserts null value in imagename and imagepath columns.  This is my stored procedure:

```
alter PROCEDURE PB_Insertgallery   
  @XmlString nText
AS
BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @XMLDocPointer INT  

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XMLDocPointer OUTPUT, @XmlString     
   INSERT INTO tb_gallery
   (imagename, imagepath)    
   SELECT imagename,imagepath
   FROM OPENXML(@XMLDocPointer,'/NewDataSet/Table1',2)    
    WITH  (imagename VARCHAR(max),  --'@ImageName',     
         imagepath VARCHAR(max)     --'@ImagePath'
          )   
   EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @XMLDocPointer 
END
GO
```

And the xml string is:

```
<NewDataSet>
     <Table1>
          <Imagename>Chrysanthemum.jpg</Imagename>
          <Imagepath>/prop_images/temp/Chrysanthemum.jpg</Imagepath>
     </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

Please help me out; why i am getting null value during insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to case sensitivity, your imagename, imagepath in the SQL is lower case where it has some uppercase in the ntext.

```
alter PROCEDURE test   
  @XmlString nText,
  @Propertyid Varchar(100),
  @Builderid Varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @XMLDocPointer INT  

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XMLDocPointer OUTPUT, @XmlString     
   INSERT INTO tb_gallery
   (Imagename, Imagepath, Propertyid, Builderid)    
   SELECT Imagename,Imagepath, @Propertyid, @Builderid
   FROM OPENXML(@XMLDocPointer,'/NewDataSet/Table1',2)    
    WITH  (Imagename VARCHAR(max),  --'@ImageName',     
         Imagepath VARCHAR(max)     --'@ImagePath'
          )   
   EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @XMLDocPointer 
END
GO
```

Comment: I tested this and confirmed nulls before and successful output after. Your syntax is all correct.

Comment: one more thing I want to ask that suppose..there are 2 more fields in my db..which are @@Propertyid and @@BuilderId .. I am passing two other paramters along with it which is @@Propertyid and @@BuilderId a s parameter and then after I want that too to insert along with it..how can i do that..?

Comment: I don't understand your additional question. Are you saying you're passing two more variables to the procedure and you want to insert them as well? Where are they being inserted? Into the same table?

Comment: I modified my answer to show it. You simply append them to your resultset as static variables.